# How to check the nested objects are equal or not in Junit5

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

When a method returns a nested object as a response than how can we test that method?
I am writing the code in java 8 and junit5.
I have POJOs like below

```
Class Phone{
  int id;
  String name;
}
Class Address{
String street;
String city;
}
Class Person {
 List<Phone> phones;
 Address address;
 String name;
}
```

I have a method like below

```
public Person getPerson(String name){
return persons.stream().filter(person -> person.getName().equals(name)).findAny().orElse(null);
}
```

Here, How can I test this method with junit5?

Comment: You can just [`assertEquals(Object , Object)`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertEquals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-)... You have to make sure the `equals()` method of your object is working correctly.

Comment: When I use the assertEquals, It failed
Here We have a List of phones. Thanks

Comment: Use `assertj` if you wan't assert `Collections` or `Map`.
check here: https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-examples/blob/master/assertions-examples/src/test/java/org/assertj/examples/IterableAssertionsExamples.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to user the [assertEquals()](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html) method in JUnit. Note that, as you can see in the [code](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/blob/master/src/main/java/junit/framework/Assert.java) of the method, it uses the .equals() method.

So, in order for it to work, you should override the equals method in each of the classes whose objects you are trying to test/compare.